# Create XML Document from URL

Tags: java, android, xml, url, document

I have this method:

```
@Override
    protected Document doInBackground(String... params) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            return factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(url.openStream());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

Instead of returning Document containing the XML file I am attempting to parse, this method returns a Document containing: `org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.DocumentImpl@3f9ee43b`

Comment: I'm confused. What is in the URL? Are you getting a Json or something similar from it?

Comment: Any RSS feed.  I am referencing it wrong?

Comment: You can check out these links: [Link1](http://code.google.com/p/android-rss/), [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4051002/4261022) [Link3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24985128/4261022). Hope it helps!